# Cordova plugin to send breadcrumb information to iOS SDK

Tags: cordova

I am currently supporting a mobile app where coding was done on standard web technology tools and we are using cordova plugin to interact with iOS.

There is a requirement for us that we should send some session information, breadcrumb information to AppD. To find the user experience about how much time he spent on a page etc....

In case of a native app, AppD has already exposed certain APIs in their SDK, but in our case it is a hybrid app and I need some pointers/suggestions about how to send such information to AppD.

Comment: What is an "AppD"?

Answer (score 0):

If your analytics vendor doesn't provide a Cordova SDK for AppD, the best solution is to write a Cordova plugin to wrap the native iOS and Android SDKs. The Cordova plugin can provide a common analytics API in JavaScript so it works on both platforms.